# Understanding address of values and dereferecing pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to have a better understanding of pointers and how they work. I'm also trying to understand the idea of dereferencing pointers. This is my understanding of pointers, and what may be possible of pointers.
This is a table representing 3 cells of memory. In each cell there is an address, cell name, and value.

```
+---------------------------+
| 1672 x | 1673 y | 5       |
|  1673  |   5    |   65    |
+---------------------------+
```

This is the initialization for the three cell blocks, assuming address 5 hasn't been initialized.

```
int x = 1673;
int y = 5;
```

This is how pointers are commonly used.

```
int* p_x = &x; //&x == 1672);
*p_x == 1673;
```

This would be true if you forgot to place ampersand in from of variable name.

```
int* p_y = y; //y == 5);
*p_y == 65;
```

If everything else is true would this also be true? If you were using the pointer to the address of x for a simple return on a member function, could you just skip a declaration of the pointer and just send the dereferenced address?

```
*&x == &y;
```

The lines with `==` will not compile, and are not actual c++ code. They are just an effective way to show equivalency.

Comment: Save Edits
cancel
help
478 characters left
Conceptually, yes: `*&x` is equivalent to `x`, which is `1673`. In your particular case `1673` is also the address of `y`.

Comment: `int* p_x = (&x == 1672);` This is not valid C++ and wouldn't compile. Is it meant to be some kind of pseudocode notation? If so, I don't understand what it's supposed to represent. Same is true of `int* p_y = (y == 5);` and `*&x == &y;`